# Error installing texlive: fail to install media9

Tags: texlive, installing, tlmgr

Tex live has been installing on my PC for a full 3h now and after all that time I got the following error message:

```
*** PLEASE READ THIS WARNING ***********************************

The following (inessential) packages failed to install properly:

  media9

You can fix this by running this command:
  tlmgr update --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed
to complete the installation.

However, if the problem was a failure to download (by far the
most common cause), check that you can connect to the chosen mirror
in a browser; you may need to specify a mirror explicitly.
******************************************************************
```

I tried to run the command line it suggests, but my PC still can't install the package it's talking about. Does anyone know how else this can be fixed? Or whether it's safe to just close the installation even without this package and the program will still work?

Comment: as the message you  quote says.  You just failed on one package, I've used tex for over 30 years and I don't think I have used it so you will probably manage and anyway it is probably an issue with your local mirror and will fix itself tomorrow